# how to use the foreach loop to pass each row of a wpf datagridview with Thesame data source as a report back to the report

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

how can i bind my report/report Viewer to a datagrid view with the Data source as that of the report dataset?
ive created an ID card design in a Report. I bind all textbox in the report in my database fields(Data set). but when i run the program, the reportViewer only displays the data from the first rowof my database.

Now, I want to bind my report to a datagrid so i can control which row i am going to display in the reportViewer.

i have search the internet so far this is what i found;

```
DataTable dtRep = ((DataTable)dgv.DataSource).Clone();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.SelectedRows)
        {
            dtRep.ImportRow(((DataTable)dgv.DataSource).Rows[row.Index]);
        }
        dtRep.AcceptChanges();
```

but this doesn't work in wpf can some one help me with a code that could help me accomplish this? (thanks)

UPDATE
am very sorry i run out of credit while uploading the question please pardon my ignorance;

HERE IS the image of my error from my code;

```
DataTable dtRep = ((DataTable)dgvRESULTPRINTER.ItemsSource).Clone();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvRESULTPRINTER.SelectedItems)
    {
        dtRep.ImportRow(((DataTable)dgvRESULTPRINTER.DataSource).Rows[row.Index]);
    }
    dtRep.AcceptChanges();
```

[image]

Comment: It is difficult to follow what you are asking. It is unclear how the code relates to question text. The code appears to import/copy the “selected” rows in the grid… from the grids data table (data source)… to a new data table. In my tests, the code appears to work and it is not clear what _”doesn’t work”_ means. What specifically doesn’t work in relation to the posted code?

Comment: You need to make it clear what platform you are targeting... WPF or Winforms. There is no `DataGridView` control in WPF. In addition, the code appears to mix a grid’s `DataSource` and `ItemsSource` in ways that are not possible. As it stands now, the code will not work in either platform for numerous reasons. Please clarify this for your sake and ours. If you are using WPF, then remove the `DataGridView` tag and switch it to `DataGrid`. If you are using Winforms then remove the WPF tag. The WPF and DataGridView tags are missing your target audience as they do not belong together.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, it is not clear what platform you are targeting. Therefore, below is an example using both a WInforms platform and a WPF platform.

For a Winforms, I assume the `DataSource` for the grid is a `DataView.` In that case you need to convert the `DataView` to a `DataTable` to get the table’s cloned schema. It may look something like…

```
DataTable dtRep = ((DataView)dgvRESULTPRINTER.DataSource).ToTable().Clone();
foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in dgvRESULTPRINTER.SelectedRows) {
  dtRep.ImportRow(((DataRowView)dgvr.DataBoundItem).Row);
}
```

For a WPF, I will also assume that the grids `ItemsSource` is a `DataView`, and it may look something like…

```
DataTable dtRep = ((DataView)DataGrid1.ItemsSource).ToTable().Clone();
foreach (DataRowView drv in DataGrid1.SelectedItems) {
  dtRep.ImportRow(drv.Row);
}
```

Edit per OP comment...

Below is doing the same thing using a `for` loop. It is difficult to understand what you mean by your comment…

> *”… so that i will import just one specific row only to the report”* ?

If you only want ONE (1) specific row, then what is the `for` or `foreach` loop for? Just grab the “selected” row you want. I am guessing there is more to this than you are revealing.

```
for (int i = 0; i < DataGrid1.SelectedItems.Count; i++) {
  dtRep.ImportRow(((DataRowView)DataGrid1.SelectedItems[i]).Row);
}
```

Comment: thanks very much; it really helped, but please can i use the FOR(...) statement to do the same thing i did with "foreach" so that i will import just one specific row only to the report  (thanks)

Comment: ok sir thank very much, all your code works perfectly cool; but if i can get more simplified form for my code i would be happy; can you make a code expressing what  you mean by "GRABING SELECTED ROW YOU WANT" please to make my work easy (thanks)

Comment: Hmmm… What do you think the line of code: … `dtRep.ImportRow(((DataRowView)DataGrid1.SelectedItems[i]).Row);` … is doing?

Comment: Thanks very much God bless your ideas